# No funciona MercadoEnvíos en Prestashop

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy tratando de hacer funcionar MercadoEnvíos en mi sitio con Prestashop y no logro hacerlo funcionar.
Ya me bajé el módulo oficial de Mercado Pago, lo instalé y configuré.
MercadoPago funciona Perfectamente, pero cuando ingreso al carrito, en la opción de transportistas no logro hacer que lo muestre.
En la sección de transportista están activado las dos opciones estándar y prioritario.
Cual puede ser el problema? Porque estoy cansado de enviarle consultas a Mercado pago y nunca me da una respuesta. No tiene soporte. Todo pago por lo menos te da un soporte y se fijan que está funcionando mal. 
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Saludos.

Comment: desgraciadamente, no somos el soporte de mercadopago, por mas que ellos te hayan dirigido aca.. En su formato actual, tu pregunta no tendria una respuesta correcta acorde a los estandares del sitio. visita [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si necesitas mas ayuda sobre como preguntar o que tipo de preguntas son validas en el sitio.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no somos el soporte técnico de Mercado Pago

Comment: Elio, tu pregunta no cumple con las políticas de calidad de la comunidad. Por favor, lee esta guía __[ask]__ y edita tu pregunta para incluir un __[mcve]__ que ayude a comprender tu problema. Limita tu pregunta al problema de programación real y concreto al que te enfrentas y evita las quejas y críticas, ya que no son relevantes para la resolución de error que tienes en tu código.